# How to use Django's session authentication with Django Channels?

Tags: django, reactjs, authentication, websocket, django-channels

I am developing a chess web app using Django, Django Channels and React. I am using websockets for the game play between the online players and for getting updated which players are now online and available to play. However I am stuck on the authentication part. I first started with token authentication, but I found that it is not possible to send custom headers with the token in them as part of the websocket request. Then I went back to the default django.contrib.auth session authentication. Unfortunately, when the client logs in and connects to the websocket I am not able to get their user info as if the user is using a different session with the websocket. I get the value **AnonymousUser** when I print **self.scope["user"]** in the websocket consumers. Note that I am able to exchange messages using the websocket, and the authentication works well with normal http requests as I can prevent users who are not logged in from accessing views.

I am guessing the problem is related to the fact that websocket requests on the client side don't access or use the cookie for the authentication like the http requests.

Has anybody faced a similar problem and how did they fix it?

This is how I send the websocket message in react:

```
submitMessage = (evt) => {
    //console.log("token in Messenger=",this.props.token);
    evt.preventDefault();
    const message = { message: this.state.message_to_send}
    this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(message))
  }
```

This is the backend code for handling the websocket requests:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import json
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

class LoggedUsersConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        print(self.scope)
        print(self.user,"+++++++++++++")
        #Join group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            "logged_users",
            self.channel_name
        )
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            "logged_users",
            self.channel_name
        )

    def receive(self, text_data):
        self.user = self.scope["user"]
        print(self.user,"+++++++++++++")

        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        print(text_data_json)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "logged_users",
            {
                'type': 'logged_user_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    def logged_user_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right, you probably do not have a session-cookie for requests from the client side that's why you get **AnonymousUser**. I don't think this has anything to do with how you handle websocket requests neither in React nor in Django.

Please check your browser's cookies in your React frontend (through the Developer Tools in Chrome/Firefox). You should have at least 2 cookies, csrftoken and sessionid. If any of these are lacking, the following might help you in the right direction. I experienced the same when developing with Vue, Django Channels and Django Rest Framework.

If you visit your Django backend through your browser, the HTML-templates and your browser takes care of setting the cookies. When you do this from React or Vue, the HTML is not rendered. Therefore you need to implement authentication and the setting of cookies yourself. And of course you need to authenticate from React in the same session as you later use for accessing the web-sockets.

I use the following Django-views to authenticate from the frontend:

```
@api_view()
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@ensure_csrf_cookie
@csrf_exempt
def session_info(request):
    """
    View to retrieve user info for current user. (Can be adapted to your needs). If user is not logged in, view will
    still return CSRF cookie which in neccessary for authentication.
    """
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response({"message": "Not authenticated.", "authenticated": False})
    return Response(
        {"message": "Authenticated.", "authenticated": True, "user": str(request.user)}
    )


@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def session_auth(request):
    """
    Login-view.
    """
    username = request.data['username']
    password = request.data['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            request.session['authenticated_user'] = user.username
            return Response(
                {
                    "message": "Authenticated.",
                    "authenticated": True,
                    "name": user.name,
                }
            )
    return Response({"message": "Not authenticated", "authenticated": False})
```

In your urls.py you need to add something like the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'session/',
        views.session_info,
        name='session',
    ),
    path(
        'sessionauth/',
        views.session_auth,
        name='sessionauth',
    ),
]
```

Now you can from your frontend do something like this (the following is my javascript/Vue-code, slightly adapted for this post, but you can probably do something similar with React):

```
// Please note: this code can probably be improved a lot as my skills in javascript are not the best
login: ({ username, password }) => {
    window.$cookies.set("username", username);
    const session_url = `${BACKEND_URL}/api/v1/session/`;
    const url = `${BACKEND_URL}/api/v1/sessionauth/`;

    axios.get(session_url).then(response => {      
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "";
      // NOTE: the CSRF-cookie need to be included in subsequent POSTs:
      axios.defaults.headers.post["X-CSRF-Token"] = response.data._csrf;
      axios
        .post(url, { username: username, password: password })
        .then(response => {
          axios.get(session_url);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log("ERROR: ", e);
          commit("SET_LOGIN_ERROR", e);
        });
    });
```

I hope this is of some help. If not, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Let me just add this in case it might help someone,

You always get **AnonymousUser** because probably you are not passing the cookie header right.

with session authentcation, pass the session header like this.

```
Cookie: csrftoken=wBD7Qri09dyAR8oMY8fuL1nqCOvGGmaO; sessionid=hpb8xx873holf3zl01wfe6f7511bhxqi
```

You might try to do

```
Set-Cookie: sessionid=hpb8xx873holf3zl01wfe6f7511bhxqi;
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=wBD7Qri09dyAR8oMY8fuL1nqCOvGGmaO;
```

That won't work.